# Alternative for the width:"" in chrome and safari

Tags: html, css

In my page i have used "div" for store the images.In that div is act as the container of three images.if i set the width as width:"" it takes the default width of the parent.But in chrome and safari it not works.i think its return 0 as width of div.So what is the alternative for the width:"" in chrome and safari?

Comment: This question is difficult to understand. Try to be as clear as possible. If you are able to have someone help with the English grammar, it would help us understand your problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<img style="width:auto">
```

Comment: Hi Andrey,I have used width property in javascript for set the default width of div.If i have tried width:auto.Its not working properly.Is there any other way?

Comment: function coinSlide(id) {
                    id = '#'+id.replace(/:/g, "\\:");
                    var sliderWidth="auto";          
                        jQuery(id).coinslider({width:sliderWidth,height:screen.height/4,delay:500});
                    }